# useEffect Hook Not Firing After State Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two sibling components that share state via context in react.
The shared state between the components is an array.

If I update `arr` state in one component, I want the other component to listen for that update and do something accordingly. When I use `useEffect` in the second component, I listen for changes in the `arr` state variable.

For example:

```
// App Component -------
const App = props => {
 const { arr, setArr } = useContext(GlobalContext)
  
 const handleChange = () => {
   const newArr = arr
   [10, 20, 30, 40].map(v => {
     newArr.push(v)
     setArr(newArr)
   })

  return (...)
}

// App2 (Sibling) Component 
const App2 = props => {
  const { arr, setArr } = useContext(GlobalContext)
  const [localArr, setLocalArr] = useState(0)

  useEffect(
    () => {
      updateLocalState()
    },
    // fire if "arr" gets updated
    [arr]
  )

  const updateLocalState = () => {
    setLocalArr(localArr + 1)
  }

  return (...)
}
```

The `useEffect` hook is *only* fired on the initial render, though the state of `arr` updates.

I know that declaring a new variable `const newArr = arr` to my state variable is a reference, so `newArr.push(v)` is technically a state mutation. *However, the state still updates, no warning is thrown, and `useEffect` does nothing.*

Why does `useEffect` not get called though the state gets updated? Is it because of the state mutation?

Second Question: Why is there no warning or error thrown regarding a state mutation? State mutations are dangerous - If it happens, I'd expect some sort of warning.

Live demo here:

[image: Edit 7wzlo8y4m1]

Comment: You never create a new array. `const newArr = arr` references the same array with another variable. Try e.g. `const newArr = [...arr]` instead.

Comment: It is a reference to the same array, but that doesn't explain why `useEffect` doesn't fire though the state still updates.

Comment: The array you pass as second argument to `useEffect` only checks if the elements in the array are `===` to the elements in it in the previous render. `const newArr = arr;` will lead to `newArr === arr`, which is not what you want.

Comment: what @Tholle says, just changing `setArr([...newArr])` fires `useEffect` correctly

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev your comment solved my problem! Thanks a TON.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev thanks a lot. I was coding in circles, trying useRef, useLayoutEffect and whatever. You saved me out of my 2 hour jurney. Thank you!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The array you pass as second argument to `useEffect` only checks if the elements in the array are `===` to the elements in it in the previous render. `const newArr = arr;` will lead to `newArr === arr` since it doesn't create a new array, which is not what you want.

Create a new array with all the elements in `arr` and it will work as expected.

```
const App = props => {
 const { arr, setArr } = useContext(GlobalContext)

 const handleChange = () => {
   const newArr = [...arr]
   [10, 20, 30, 40].forEach(v => {
     newArr.push(v)
   })
   setArr(newArr)
 }

  return <>{/* ... */}</>
}
```

Comment: I think it might be worth showcasing a better practice for this block of code - something as simple as `setArr([...arr, 10, 20, 30, 40])`

Comment: I hadn't considered the diffing algorithm in useEffect being a strict comparison and it being the same object for that comparison. That makes sense.

Comment: I wonder why no error or warning gets thrown about the state mutation?

Comment: @lsimonetti There's no straight-forward way for React to check for mutation let alone warn when you do it, sadly. It's just a limitation of the language.

Comment: This helps but i am still confused.

Answer (score 23):

When you want to update array using useState hook. Make sure to spread the array into new array and update the new array so that your useEffect listening for this state will be called.

UseEffect **will not call** in the below code snippet as you are directly updating array.

```
const [skills, selectedSkills] = useState([])

     const onSelect = (selectedList) => {
            selectedSkills(selectedList)
        }
     useEffect(() => {
            MyLogger('useEffect called')
        }, [skills])
```

UseEffect **will call** in the below code snippet as we are keeping new reference to the array.

```
const [skills, selectedSkills] = useState([])

     const onSelect = (selectedList) => {
            const tempSelectedList = [...selectedList]
            selectedSkills(tempSelectedList)
        }
     useEffect(() => {
            MyLogger('useEffect called')
        }, [skills])
```

Comment: misleading answer. you do not know if `selectedList` in the first example is mutated or is a new array

Comment: my problem was that i forgot to put my variable in the array at the bottom, where you have [skills]